# How to change popup menu color in material3

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-design, material3

How can i change popup menu background color in material3. I have tried a lot but found no solutions. I had tried itemBacgroundColor also but it’s still in different color. I want it to white.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy1EQ.jpg

Comment: check `android:popupMenuBackground`. define style in app theme or custom style you can set popupmenu background. check more here: https://m3.material.io/components/menus/implementation/android